# Run shell script with additional parameters from python and get output as python variable (API authentication)

Tags: python, api, python-requests

Could someone help me with the following:

I have this line that I normally run in terminal:

```
 path/to/mysh/script.sh PROD generate-ticket username
```

and it gives me the following output in terminal:

```
{"user":{"Userid":123,"firstName":"Joe","SecondName":"Doe","loginName":"jdoe"},"accessToken":"1235df6543cggf432sa24"}
```

I need the 'accessToken' value assigned to python variable.

My code:

```
import subprocess
import json 

username ='jdoe'

def get_Access_Token(username):
    s = json.loads(subprocess.check_output(['path/to/mysh/script.sh', 'PROD', 'generate-ticket', username]))


print (s['accessToken'])
```

but it gives me the following error when trying to print my variable:

```
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the value from the function.

**Ex:**

```
import subprocess
import json 

username ='jdoe'

def get_Access_Token(username):
    return json.loads(subprocess.check_output(['path/to/mysh/script.sh', 'PROD', 'generate-ticket', username]))['accessToken']

print (get_Access_Token(username))
```